# Logic-modus pones/tollens

Tags: logic

Given:
p1: If John has bought a lottery ticket, he will win
p2: John wins
c1: Therefore, he has bought a lottery ticket

p1: If John has bought a lottery ticket, he will win
p2: John does not win
c1: Therefore, he has not bought a lottery ticket

The solution says that the first one is not a logically valid conclusion, but the second one is a logically valid conclusion (Modus tollens)

For me they seem both to be valid. I don't quite understand this

Comment: You can only say that $p1\land p2 \implies c1$ if you know that John can only win if he buys a lottery ticket, which is not stated.

Comment: In the first case, the proposition "John was given the winning lottery ticket" is consistent with the premises.

Comment: In the first case John may have won without **buying** the winning ticket (it was given to him, he stole it ...) so the conclusion doesn't stand

Answer (score 1):

An argument is valid when it is not possible for the conclusion to be false when the premises are true.

$B\to W, W\vDash B$ is not a valid inference.   It is possible for John to win by other means than *buying* a lottery ticket (eg: he could have received a winning ticket as a gift, or something).

$B\to W,\neg W\vDash \neg B$ is a valid inference.    If John is actually guaranteed to win when buying a ticket, and John did not in fact win, then it is not possible that John bought a lottery ticket.   (Because he would have won if he had.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not surprising that you are confused about this example. Let me explain:

What the book is trying to do is to show that an argument of the form:

$p \rightarrow q$

$q$

$\therefore p$

is not valid, but that:

$p \rightarrow q$

$\neg q$

$\therefore \neg p$

is valid.

The first (invalid) argument form is better known as the Fallacy of Affirming the Consequent, while the second (valid) argument form is known as Modus Tollens.

Note how the first argument you were asked to evaluate is indeed of the Affirming the Consequent form, using $L$ for John buying a lottery ticket and $W$ for John winning the lottery:

$L \rightarrow W$

$W$

$\therefore L$

And the second argument given to you follows Modus Tollens:

$L \rightarrow W$

$\neg W$

$\therefore \neg L$

OK, but why exactly is the Affirming the Consequent pattern fallacious? Well, if you set $p$ to false, and $q$ to true, you will find that the premises are true, but the conclusion false, meaning it is invalid. Alternatively, we can consider the following argument, which also follows the Affirming the Consequent pattern:

'If it is my birth day, then I am happy'

'I am happy'

'Therefore, it is my birthday'

I think it is clear why this argument is invalid: sure, it may well be true that I am happy whenever it is my birthday, but that does not mean that it is my birthday just because you know i am happy; I can of course be happy for many other reasons.

Now, that all being said, I am not surprised that the argument you were given still looks valid, and that is because it is far from clear that John (or anyone) could win the lottery without having bought a ticket. That is, there may be many ways to be happy without it being one's birthday, but are there really any ways to win the lottery without having bought a ticket?!

Still, with some creativity, we can think of such a scenario: maybe John didn't buy a lottery ticket, but a friend of his did, and gave the ticket to John. And so, in the end, the argument does turn out to really be invalid. It is not the most clear example ... but maybe that's just the power of logic: the formal logical analysis shows that the first argument is invalid, even though it certainly looks to be valid.